# IE7: Footer not sticking to bottom of division container when accordions change number/size

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, accordion, internet-explorer-7, sticky-footer

I have a couple of pages in a site in which I'm using jquery accordions.  In the browsers other than IE7, everything works fine.  In IE7, the footer on the pages stays where it was originally drawn (unless the browser window is re-sized).  When selecting another tab with a different number of accordions or minimizing an accordion, the footer does not stick to the bottom of the container. If the content expands, that expanded container goes under the footer, and the user cannot interface with that area...  If the content shrinks, the footer stays where originally drawn..

How do I get the footer to stick on in IE7 when the accordions change the height of the content area???

Links to pages ("projects" is large and my cloud is disabled, "awards" link faster)

http://iliveinyourhead.net/awards

http://iliveinyourhead.net/projects

Any help greatly appreciated...  Thanks.

Comment: it's working ok for me in IE7. Though I'm using the dev tools and using IE7 and IE7 standards.

Comment: Just making sure the issue is understood...  The footer is fine when the page is originally drawn.  The issue is when accordions change the height of the content area in IE7.  The user that showed me the issue is using is 7.0.5730.13, if that makes any difference.

Comment: so did you get this working on his machine? I just checked it again and it looks fine to me. On load, the footer is where it is. When I click on various accordions, the footer stays where it should be.. pushed down with the new height of the accordion. So it's not getting covered up on my machine.

Comment: No, I have not...  Still not behaving properly.  Cleared the user's cache and reloaded the page.  Still not working.

Comment: I have been able to replicate the problem...  Place a later version Internet Explorer in compatibility mode for older browsers, then click a tab that extends the accordions downwards.  It is repeatable.

Comment: but in the "compatible mode" have you also specified the 'standards' mode? Your page has a doctype so it shouldn't render in quirks mode which may be how/where you see issues. You could also try using a 4.01 transitional doctype for the heck of it: (<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> )

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to fix this in IE compatibility mode by changing:

```
footer { 
    display: block;
}
```

to

```
footer {
    [if lt IE 8] display: inline;
    [if gt IE 7] display: block;
    [if ! IE] display: block; 
}
```